# What values to use for packet and frame size with AudioUnit

Tags: cocoa, audio, frame, packet, audiounit

I am familiarizing myself with how to use AudioUnit to play sounds and am confused by the notions of packets and frames.  I would like to know:

- what is the definition of a packet and a frame in the context of AudioUnit
- what are the trades for using multiple samples per packet, and multiple packets per frame

My reason for asking: In all code samples I saw so far, a packet is essentially a sample, with typically mBytesPerPacket=4 for a 16-bit stereo stream. And mFramesPerPacket is typically 1, making a frame, a packet, and a sample (all be it stereo sample), the same concepts.

I was expecting a packet and/or a frame to be a buffer of samples, i.e. a group of 256 or 512 consecutive samples, to which the driver could be pointed and read linearly. Reducing a frame/packet size to one sample seems to put unnecessary strain on whatever driver will be responsible for playing the data.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, some definitions:

- A *frame* is a single sample of audio data, which represents the signal's value for a single channel at a given point in time.
- A *packet* is a group of frames, usually meant to be the set of frames for all channels at a given point in time.
- A *buffer* is a group of frames delivered for processing.

You should not confuse a packet and frame, and in fact `mFramesPerPacket` should generally be set to 1. This does not mean that your AudioUnit's render method will get a callback every frame. If you want to control how often that happens, you need to set the `kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration` property to the preferred buffer size. Setting this property does not guarantee you the exact buffer size that you ask for, but the system will try to give you something close to this value.

Comment: And don't be confused if the simulator seems not to respond to your requested `kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration`, as this property, from my experience, influences only the device.

Comment: @Itamar Yep, great point. The simulator uses the system's CoreAudio configuration, and therefore behaves quite a bit differently than iOS in several respects, including this one.

Comment: Thank you. Clarifications and defs much appreciated.

Comment: What is thes size of frame in m4a format? cant get amplitude value (

Comment: Just to clarify the clarification, according to the Core Audio Glossary, a *frame* is 'a set of samples that contains one sample from each channel in an audio data stream'. In other words, a frame contains a sample for *all* channels, not just one.